# How to check if a value was ever a key in a map in java

Tags: java

I'm working with Map and I want to know if it's possible to check if a value existed as a key in a map.
This is the map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> labelIdentifiersmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
labelIdentifiersmap.put(labelName, labelNameList);
```

The map has the following output:

```
Gets=[g1, g2], IMOVE=[i1, i2, i3, i8], IGET=[i4, i5, i6, i7], Inits=[IMOVE, IGET], Updates=[u1, u2, u3, u4, u5], FIN=[f2, f4, f5, f6, f7], FINALS=[FIN, f1, f3]}
```

Here `IMOVE` and `IGET` are first used as `Keys` and later they are the `Values` for `Inits` and similarly `FIN` is a `key` and later `value` for `FINALS`. Is it possible to implement a check to see if the values were keys in a map?

Comment: You can use `.containsKey(key_element)` on map

Comment: You can only check if a key currently exists, you cannot check if it did exist before and was removed. To do that, you'd need to keep an extra `Set` of all keys and sync that with the `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your `Map` in question

```
    Map<String,List<String>> labelIdentifiersmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "Gets", List.of( "g1", "g2" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "IMOVE", List.of( "i1", "i2", "i3", "i8" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "IGET", List.of( "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "Inits", List.of( "IMOVE", "IGET" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "Updates", List.of( "u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "FIN", List.of( "f2", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7" ) );
    labelIdentifiersmap.put( "FINALS", List.of( "FIN", "f1", "f3" ) );
```

If you are looking for an answer without using Java `stream` API,

```
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>( labelIdentifiersmap.values() ); // Collect all the values in the map to a List
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(); // This result set will contain the keys that are present as values in the map. Set is used here to avoid duplicate results

    for( List<String> content : lists )
    {
        for( String listContent : content )
        {
            if( labelIdentifiersmap.containsKey( listContent ) ) // If the content is available as a key in the map, we add that to result set
            {
                result.add( listContent );
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println( result.toString() ); // Finally, print the result set.
```

Comment: I tried your solution too but this too works well for "Inits" thanks for another alternative. Any suggestions on how can I make this work for "Finals" too. @Klaus

Comment: @R2D2 for the above code output will be `[IMOVE, FIN, IGET]` which is the expected as per your question. Can you tell me how `Finals` should be there in the output? Because it was never a value before, it is only a key

Comment: Yes, with `Finals~ I meant `FIN`. Sorry, for the confusion. @Klaus

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check every `key` that present in any list of values in `Map`

- First collect all values into collection object
- Second stream the map and filter the keys present in values

---

```
Collections<List<String>> mapValues = labelIdentifiersmap.values()


labelIdentifiersmap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(entry->mapValues.stream().anyMatch(val->val.contains(entry.getKey()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What an abuse of streams when `containsKey` would be so much shorter and easier.

Comment: If i understand OP question, he is trying to find the key in values @Robert you can correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes I want to check if any value was ever used as a key in the map.
This solution works well for "Inits", any suggestions on how I can make this work for "Finals" as well.Thanks @Deadpool

Comment: This solution should work for every key in that map, make sure you are not doing any syntax errors @R2D2

Answer (score 1):

Check the keys in the values using **Stream API**

---

- Get the values from `entrySet`
- Flatmap the streams of `List<List<String>>` into one stream
- Filter by checking if the value exists in the map as a key
- Collect the matched result in `List<String>`

---

```
List<String> result = labelIdentifiersmap.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
                      .filter(val -> labelIdentifiersmap.containsKey(val))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

, main function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> labelIdentifiersmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("Gets", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("g1", "g2")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("IMOVE", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("i1", "i2", "i3", "i8")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("IGET", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("i4", "i5", "i6", "i7")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("Inits", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("IMOVE", "IGET")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("Updates", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("FIN", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("f2", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7")));
        labelIdentifiersmap.put("FINALS", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("FIN", "f1", "f3")));

        List<String> result = labelIdentifiersmap.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
                      .filter(val -> labelIdentifiersmap.containsKey(val))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

, output

```
[IMOVE, IGET, FIN]
```

Comment: What an abuse of streams when `containsKey` would be so much shorter and easier.

Comment: He wants to check if there any value in the list used as a key in the map

Comment: Yes I want to check if any value was ever used as a key in the map. @Robert

Comment: This solution works well for "Inits", thanks, any suggestions on how I can make this work for "Finals" as well. @sc0der

Comment: Okay, let me check that

Comment: For this part of the output where `FIN` was the key and later became the value
`FIN=[f2, f4, f5, f6, f7], FINALS=[FIN, f1, f3]}` @sc0der

Comment: The output of the result list `[IMOVE, IGET, FIN]`, what else do you want as a result?

Comment: Yes this is the output I'm trying to get. `[IMOVE, IGET, FIN]`  @sc0der

Comment: How is it working now? The code for the stream is the same or I'm missing something.@sc0der

Comment: @R2D2 I have put the complete code if there is any step missing